# Port Binding Error while doing docker-compose

Tags: docker

I'm trying to bind port 8443 through docker and even though i do not have anything running on 8443, it is throwing me an error that 8443 is already in use.

After Looking for all running ports via this cmd: sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN

`launchd       1             root    8u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f8ef2f      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN) launchd       1             root    9u  IPv4 0xbe03e516a8f9797f      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN) launchd       1             root   11u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f8ef2f      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN) launchd       1             root   12u  IPv4 0xbe03e516a8f9797f      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN) launchd       1             root   24u  IPv6 0xbe03e516bbf55a6f      0t0  TCP localhost:8021 (LISTEN) launchd       1             root   26u  IPv4 0xbe03e516d869f97f      0t0  TCP localhost:8021 (LISTEN) launchd       1             root   38u  IPv6 0xbe03e516bbf55a6f      0t0  TCP localhost:8021 (LISTEN) launchd       1             root   39u  IPv4 0xbe03e516d869f97f      0t0  TCP localhost:8021 (LISTEN) UserEvent   118             root   83u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f8d6af      0t0  TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49157 (LISTEN) UserEvent   118             root   84u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f9018f      0t0  TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49158 (LISTEN) UserEvent   118             root   85u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f907af      0t0  TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49159 (LISTEN) UserEvent   118             root   86u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f8ca6f      0t0  TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49160 (LISTEN) UserEvent   118             root   88u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f8c44f      0t0  TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49161 (LISTEN) mysqld      182           _mysql   29u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f8dccf      0t0  TCP *:33060 (LISTEN) mysqld      182           _mysql   31u  IPv6 0xbe03e516a8f8d08f      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN) mDNSRespo   272   _mdnsresponder   33u  IPv4 0xbe03e516d869d1ff      0t0  TCP *:53 (LISTEN) mDNSRespo   272   _mdnsresponder   65u  IPv6 0xbe03e516d9bd56af      0t0  TCP *:53 (LISTEN) ir_agent    338             root   10u  IPv4 0xbe03e516a8f965bf      0t0  TCP localhost:49155 (LISTEN) Spotify     795 nimish.prabhakar   59u  IPv4 0xbe03e516a968df9f      0t0  TCP *:59124 (LISTEN) Spotify     795 nimish.prabhakar  125u  IPv4 0xbe03e516beeb135f      0t0  TCP *:57621 (LISTEN) mongod      993 nimish.prabhakar   10u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bb03dd3f      0t0  TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN) PanGPS     1000             root    7u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bb03c97f      0t0  TCP localhost:4767 (LISTEN) postgres   1148 nimish.prabhakar    7u  IPv6 0xbe03e516bbf566af      0t0  TCP localhost:5432 (LISTEN) postgres   1148 nimish.prabhakar    8u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bb03e71f      0t0  TCP localhost:5432 (LISTEN) Adobe\x20  1217 nimish.prabhakar    9u  IPv4 0xbe03e516a8f9971f      0t0  TCP localhost:15292 (LISTEN) node       1258 nimish.prabhakar   26u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bb03a1ff      0t0  TCP localhost:49222 (LISTEN) node       1258 nimish.prabhakar   28u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bc0205bf      0t0  TCP localhost:49223 (LISTEN) node       1258 nimish.prabhakar   29u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bc020f9f      0t0  TCP localhost:45623 (LISTEN) node       1258 nimish.prabhakar   30u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bb03abdf      0t0  TCP localhost:52739 (LISTEN) com.docke  1350 nimish.prabhakar   11u  IPv4 0xbe03e516bc02371f      0t0  TCP localhost:49238 (LISTEN) dcagentse 46158             root    9u  IPv4 0xbe03e516d1d545bf      0t0  TCP localhost:4990 (LISTEN)`

And when I run docker-compose cmd

`Restarting front-proxy_service2_1    ... done
Restarting front-proxy_service1_1    ... done
Restarting front-proxy_front-envoy_1 ... error

ERROR: for front-proxy_front-envoy_1  Cannot restart container 479483e3a6a1bc205aaafa7c8e83bda45455c57acde22f82405963cd97d1b8b8: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint front-proxy_front-envoy_1 (75df27c2c6ad6c31a9781eb060f40bdd7f41d9ba8003c40b13dd6065bfa5421d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8443: bind: address already in use`

Cant seem to figure out what might be the issue here.

Comment: run `docker ps` to see if any containers running on port `8443`

Answer (score 0):

you can kill 8443 port

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8443)
```